# Is this possible to create the split directory structure in Java EE without using any ide

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee

These days I am thinking to create a new structure for my Java EE app such that

```
myapp
 images/
 js/
 css/
 jsp files
 WEB-INF/
  lib/
    jar files
 build.xml
 build
  classes/
    compiled jsp files
```

Is this possible to create such structure. By this structure I want to separate all my build files outside of my WEB-INF folder. I dont know is this possible and will run successfully in the web server.

If this is wrong then please let me know.

This is the first time when i am making the Java EE app. I know the standard structure of Java EE web application. Any kind of help would be appreciable.

Comment: I read about the Ant and Split Directory Environment. Here i found Ear structure. When i study EAR here i found the it works on the application server. Is this not run on web server?

Comment: I also made a ear project on eclipse. but when i saw the directory structure. i found .projectfile .manifest file .classpath files all of them has a plenty of code. Thats why i dont want to use any kind of ide. because all the necessary task has been done by that ide. I learn nothing. Please tell me the best way to learn all of them and how to use them in my project because i am not going to use any IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposedly, you can do this in servlet 3.0 compliant web servers (like Tomcat 7) by using the

```
Class-Path:
```

directive in a META-INF/Manifest.mf file (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html for more info in manifest files). The kicker is that I think in your case, you would have to use absolute paths, which is really, really bad.

However, this is rarely done and it's also in violation of, if not the letter then certainly the spirit of the servlet specification. Compiled classes should go under `WEB-INF/classes`, libraries under `WEB-INF/lib` - that is how a Java EE app should look. Why do you want to go against both standard and convention and change this?

Comment: because in spring it use .classpath file to save the compiled file in seperate directory.

Comment: Well, you shouldn't. Believe me, it's much easier if you conform to the standard, rather than try to make the standard conform to you.